# MissingSchemaError MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm doing a really basic SPA application using nodejs, expressjs and mongodb and i'm getting an MissingSchemaError when i'm trying to run the application.
It seems my db schema is not detected properly.
I thought it was a typo but its not i'm new to node js and mongodb so a littler help will be appreciated.

**monitoring.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var monitoringSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
techName: {
    type: String
},
Customer: {
    type: String
},
Description: {
    type: String
}

});

mongoose.model('monitoring', monitoringSchema);
```

**monitoringController.js**

```
const  express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const monitoring = mongoose.model('monitoring');


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render("monitoring/addOrEdit", {
    viewTitle : "Insert Problem"
});
});

 router.post('/',(req, res) => {

 console.log(req.body);
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please check. The below Link can be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832126/missingschemaerror-schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model-user

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export default mongoose.model('monitoring', monitoringSchema);
```

instead of

```
mongoose.model('monitoring', monitoringSchema);
```

You can have more informations about `export default`
 [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export)

Answer (score 0):

You can try an export model in a schema. And module export in the controller.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var monitoringSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
techName: {
    type: String
},
Customer: {
    type: String
},
Description: {
    type: String
}

});
export default model('Project', ProjectSchema);


const  express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const monitoringModel = require("../models/monitoring.model");
let monitoringController = {};


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render("monitoring/addOrEdit", {
    viewTitle : "Insert Problem"
});
});

 router.post('/',(req, res) => {

 console.log(req.body);
 });

 module.exports = monitoringController;
```

Comment: I try this way but its not working etheir still have the same error.