# Get parent data based reference ID on Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get `products` data based on `orders products` id and below is my `Order` Model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { ObjectId, String, Number } = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    products: [
        {
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            },
            product: {
                type: ObjectId,
                ref: "Product"
            }
        }
    ],
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'pending',
        enum: ["pending", "delivered"]
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});

export default mongoose.models.Order || mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

The Product Model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { String, Number } = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    productType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sku: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mediaUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});

export default mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

And the query is like below for all orders:

```
const orders = await Order.find()
    .sort({ createdAt: 'desc' })
    .populate({
        path: "products.product",
        model: "Product"
    });
// console.log(orders)
res.status(200).json({ orders });
```

The concept is when creating an order it's creating with product id and I want to fetch the products based on the order product id.

And this way it showing

> MongooseError [MissingSchemaError]: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Product".

How can I solve that?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your `Product` schema & model ?

Comment: @whoami Updated the question with the Product model. Can you please check?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832126/missingschemaerror-schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Order` model you might be import the `Product` model then in the `ref` you use without quotation like

```
ref: Product
```

That is the way I think.

Thanks